# why do i get blank page after deploying my spring boot CRUD REST Api to Azure when i try to make a request on an endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, azure, deployment, cloud

I created an Crud REST API in spring, after deploying to azure i cannot see anything on the endpoints (just a blank page). On my localhost it worked just fine.

this is the site https://app-studentiapi-231009202421.azurewebsites.net/student/2

I tried redeploying the entire app, didnt work.
I tried updating the settings from the azure portal, still didnt work.

I dont have the code posted in GIT, but the program itself its pretty simple, i have one controller and one model. Here is my controller class:

```
package com.studentComanCatalin.demo.controller;

import com.studentComanCatalin.demo.model.Student;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {
private Student student;

@GetMapping("{id}")
public Student getStudent(String id)
{
    return student;
   // return new Student("1","catalin","catalin@catalin.com", 
22);
}

@PostMapping
public String createStudent(@RequestBody Student student)
{
    this.student = student;
    return "Student created!";
}

@PutMapping
public String updateStudent(@RequestBody Student student)
{
    this.student = student;
    return "Student updated!";
}

@DeleteMapping("{id}")
public String deleteStudent( String id)
{
    this.student = null;
    return "Student deleted!";
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide code or repository link if you have your project in GitHub(excluding sensitive information).

Comment: Edited just now @PravallikaKV

Comment: How are you deploying your application? Any IDE?

Answer (score 0):

***I created a simple spring boot application and used your code with few modifications as below:***

```java
package com.example.spring_crud;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class StudentController {
    private Student student;

    @GetMapping("/student/{id}")
    public Student getStudent(String id)
    {
        System.out.println("students displayed");
        return student;
        // return new Student("1","catalin","catalin@catalin.com", 22);
    }
    @GetMapping("/student")
    public Student getStudents()
    {
        System.out.println("students displayed");
    return new Student("1","catalin","catalin@catalin.com", 22);
    }

    @PostMapping("/student")
    public String createStudent(@RequestBody Student student)
    {
        this.student = student;
        return "Student created!";
    }

    @PutMapping("/student/{id}")
    public String updateStudent(@RequestBody Student student)
    {
        this.student = student;
        return "Student updated!";
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/student/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteStudent( String id)
    {
        this.student = null;
        return "Student deleted!";
    }
}
```

**Local response:**

As I don't have any data, I could just display like below:

[image]

I have deployed the application via IntelliJ IDE:

[image]

[image]

**Deployed Successfully:**

[image]

**Azure response:**

[image]

***Refer my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/PravallikaKothaveerannagari/Springboot_H2-database_CRUD) for a sample Spring_boot CRUD Application.***

**Deployed to Azure App Service:**

[image]

[image]